# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function when converting table to datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

i have a table which is created from CSV file using AJAX , so  i just wanted to convert the table to datatable , with multiple column filter or even single filter is fine . The conversion of CSV to HTML table is working fine but it is not able to convert Table to Datatable .

Can anyone help me . Below is my code .

```
 Last refresh : <div id="time">
 <?php echo date('H:i:s');?></div><div id="employee_table"> </div>
<script>
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                                $.ajax({
                                    url:"FILES/UILatestReport.csv",
                                    dataType:"text",
                                    success:function(data)
                                    {
                                        var employee_data = data.split(/\r?\n|\r/);
                                        var table_data = '<table  id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">';
                                        for(var count = 0; count<employee_data.length; count++){
                                            var cell_data = employee_data[count].split(",");
                                            table_data += '<tr>';
                                            for(var cell_count=0; cell_count<cell_data.length; cell_count++){
                                                if(count === 0){
                                                    table_data += '<th class="headingvalues">'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</th>';
                                                }else{
                                                    if(cell_data[cell_count] == "Error"){
                                                        table_data += '<td><span class="badge badge-danger">'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</span></td>';
                                                    }else if(cell_data[cell_count] == "Down"){
                                                        table_data += '<td><span class="badge badge-danger">'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</span></td>';
                                                    }else{
                                                        table_data += '<td>'+cell_data[cell_count]+'</td>';
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            table_data += '</tr>';
                                        }
                                        table_data += '</table>';
                                        $('#employee_table').html(table_data);
                                    }
                                });
    
                                $('#myTable').DataTable();
                            });
                            </script>
```

and i have included javasript and CSS for datatable on top :

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"  src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

Comment: Most common reason for such an error is loading another version of jquery.js further down the page which wipes out plugin methods attached to the first

Comment: but still my Table is not converted to Datatable . It just appears to be Normal Table @charlietfl

Comment: Did you resolve the error? Note you should initialize the plugin within the ajax success after you populate it

Answer (score 0):

You initialize the table before the ajax call returns the answer from the server.
Since you create the HTML inside your success block,
you try to initialize an element that's not exists in your DOM.
Move

```
$('#myTable').DataTable();
```

into your success block

Comment: While this is true it doesn't explain the error thrown

Comment: Okay now error is gone , but table is not getting converted to Datatable

Comment: @GowriLakshmi can you give more details or edit your post with the updated code?